# Magento 1.7: "Place Order" disabled by default in PayPal Express Review

Tags: magento, paypal

Since Magento 1.7.0.1, the "Place Order" button on the review page of PayPal Express is disabled by default.
When the user ticks both checkboxes, it stays disabled. The user needs to tick the checkboxes  *and* click on "Update Order Data". After the site is reloaded, "Place Order"/"Kaufen" is enabled.

How can this bug be fixed? It is also present in 1.7.0.2.

[image: Disabled Process Order button]

Comment: Just out of curiosity does scrolling both agreements all the way down enable it?

Comment: This sounded too good to be true. But no, it has no effect. Even when I scroll both all way down *and* check the boxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me this is more like a bug or unexpected behavior,
because the agreements checkbox is not related with the customer
address and it doesn't have any business with PayPal express :)

I found a workaround, that works for me, but I can't say that it's
is a example of the best development practices.

**Short explanation of the problem**: The problem comes from the fact, that on the PayPal Express review page we have JavaScript functions, that activate an event handler on change of all form elements. This event handler disable the "place order" button. This should work in that way if we change for element, that is related with the customer address ... Well of course the agreement checkboxes are not related with the customer address and seems, that the folks from Magento missed, that moment :)

**Here is the solution**:

1. find file "template/paypal/review.phtml" ... if you don't have this file in your theme, just copy it from the base theme
2. Add add the lines of code after //Workaround to unbind the event listeners for the agreement checkboxes at the bottom of the file. Take the code from here: https://gist.github.com/4503260

Basically this recreates agreement checkboxes and as side effect the new checkboxes, don't have event listeners, that disable the place order button.

Hope, that it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :). What a ridiculous problem to have in the first place, god I hate magento!

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, I don't know if this helps or not but the One Step Checkout Pro extension by MageWorld may have this issue fixed in their latest release...

> v1.4.2.2
>
> *Fixed "Sales order grid" and order details in backend.
>   *Fixed "place order button is disabled" on IE.

I haven't tested it though so can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a bug, this is a feature. When the customer changes any data (shipping method eg.), the price can be changed too. And to update review table the customer should press update order button. And if he agreed with the price he will press place order button. Other technique is AJAX request to validate data and calculate prices. But you will have a lot of requests from one customer and customer will wait every time when he changes data.